# EJB3 - method not a post-construct method of EJB interceptor

Tags: ejb-3.0, postconstruct

My @PostConstruct method meets all of the rules, but I still get the error that the method is not a post-construct method of EJB interceptor.

It's return is void.  It does not throw exceptions.  It does not take arguments.

Does anyone know of another reason that this error can occur?

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        getReferences();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The method MUST NOT have any parameters except in the case of EJB
>   interceptors in which case it takes an ***InvocationContext*** object as
>   defined by the EJB specification.

As you have mentioned it is an EJB interceptor, I believe you need to add a parameter for InvocationContext.